# Cannot POST data to server using RestClient with C# Xamarin and Android

Tags: c#, php, android, post, xamarin

I have tried posting to the server using the following code:

C#:

```
myButton.Click += delegate
{
    var url = "https://www.myurl.com/test.php";
    var client = new RestClient(url);
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.AddParameter("A", "foo");
    request.AddParameter("B", "bar");
    var response = client.Execute(request);
    textView.Text = response.Content;
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    die('aaa'.$_POST['A'].$_POST['B']);
?>
```

The `textView` is being set to 'aaa', so it's receiving data from the server. The problem is the `$_POST` data is not being sent with `request.AddParameter`. I have also tried with `var client = new RestClient("Resource", url);`. That doesn't work either. Maybe `"Resource"` is incorrect.